# Ruby self in method chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have defined two scope-like methods on a model:

```
def self.foo var
  where(foo: var)
end

def self.bar var
  where(bar: var)
end
```

I want to be able to pass nil to one of these methods and have it effectively be ignored. So:

```
var1 = 10
var2 = nil
# ...
Model.foo(var1).bar(var2)
```

I've tried various things such as:

```
def self.bar var
  return self if var.nil?
  where(bar: var)
end
```

but in the above instance, `self` doesn't return what this method has been passed from the previous method in the chain, it returns `Model`, therefore I lose all the legwork done in `foo`.

How can I achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: Did you try something like `all()` if it's nil? I have no idea if that would work. I'm also not a fan of this pattern; I think it's misleading.

Comment: I did try `all`, but that returns an array so if I had another scope on the end I'd get `undefined method 'where' for #<Array:....` for example. I know it's a rubbishy pattern, but I don't really get why there's a disparity between what `self` returns and whatever `where` acts on in the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in rails 3.x, you should be able to use something like this:

```
return self.scoped if var.nil?
```

In rails 4.x, you'll need to change that to:

```
return self.all if var.nil?
```

Basically, 'scoped' (and in rails 4 'all') returns a relation object that you can chain with other arel methods, without actually applying any conditions to it.

Comment: `self.scoped`, well I never.. thanks @sockmonk! knew there had to be something like it.

Answer (score 1):

`all` will actually **run the query vs returning an `ActiveRelation`** object, which is to be used to lazy load the query just when it actually needs to return the results (ex: when you actually run `each`). Else, it doesn't execute the query at all, saving you a call to the Database. It also allows for the nice chaining you are basically trying to achieve here.

What you may want to try is

```
def self.bar(val)
  return where({}) if val.nil?
  where(:bar => val)
end
```